# Syncfusion TaskBar binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, syncfusion

Im trying to bind a [Syncfusion TaskBar](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/task-bar) to an ObservableCollection, and have a list of TaskBarItems.
Using code-behind, items are added like this:

```
TaskBar taskBar = new TaskBar();
TaskBarItem taskBarItem1 = new TaskBarItem();
taskBarItem1.Header = "TaskBarItem1";
TextBlock textBlock1 = new TextBlock();
textBlock1.Text = "This TaskBar that have a TaskBarItem.";
taskBarItem1.Items.Add(textBlock1);          
taskBar.Items.Add(taskBarItem1);
```

This XAML:

```
<syncfusion:TaskBar Grid.Row="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Categories, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=localV:MainWindow}}">
    <syncfusion:TaskBar.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </syncfusion:TaskBar.ItemTemplate>
</syncfusion:TaskBar>
```

gives me a list of TaskBarItems, with Header showing FirstName, and nothing in the expandable area of any TaskBarItem. How can I make proper bindings/templates to see both Header and data in the expandable area?

Comment: Can you explain for what purpose you are using TaskBar control in your application? So we may have better idea to suggest solution based on it.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect you to be able to define an `ItemContainerStyle` or a `ContentTemplate`:

```
<syncfusion:TaskBar Grid.Row="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Categories, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=localV:MainWindow}}">
    <syncfusion:TaskBar.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="syncfusion:TaskBarItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock>This TaskBar that have a TaskBarItem</TextBlock>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </syncfusion:TaskBar.ItemContainerStyle>
</syncfusion:TaskBar>
```

Comment: It did half of the work, binding the Header. But TaskBarItem is not a Content control - it doesn't have 'Content' property, it uses Children instead. Is it possible to bind Children, without creating a DependencyProperty?